# MVC ViewModel issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a viewmodel that has 2 properties, first property is a Model object and the second property is a List . In my View i have 2 parts.

First part populates the data for the first object, Firstname,lastname,email and some other stuff.

The second part of my view is a webgrid that a user adds multiple address.

Now what is my problem, i have a JSON action on my controller that gets the data from the form, adds them to the viewmodel List property, but nothing happens.

I checked that the data is coming from the view, added to the viewmodel but each time the viewmodel is empty.

```
[Authorize]
public JsonResult addAddress(Address addr, CustomerViewModel model)
{
    if (model.CAddress== null)
        model.CAddress= new List<Address>();

    model.CAddress.Add(addr);

    return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I am using Javascript :

```
function AddAddress() 
{ 
 var addID = $("#lstID option:selected").val(); 
 var addName = $("#lstAddName option:selected").text(); 

 var Address = 
 { 
  addID : addID.toString(), 
  addName : addName.toString() 
 }; 

$.ajax({ 
 type: "POST", 
 url: "@Url.Action("addAddress","Customer")", 
 dataType: "json", contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
 data: JSON.stringify(Address), 
 success: function (data) {} }); };
```

Comment: Have you fired up Fiddler to see if there is an error?

Comment: I don't use fiddler, i have a Chrome extension that shows me if i have any javascript errors. I don't get any errors from javascript. But cant seem to get this working.

Comment: trust me, try fiddler, see the 500 error.

Comment: Tried out Fiddler, no errors.

Comment: how are you posting the data from the form?

Comment: please update your question. hard to read that as a comment

Comment: updated my answer so the code is displayed correctly.

Comment: why is the viewmodel empty when my function in my controller gets called? shouldn't it have data in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, start by writing a real view model, not some hybrids:

```
public class CustomerViewModel 
{
    public List<AddressViewModel> Addresses { get; set; }

    ... some other properties you already had
}

public class AddressViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

then adapt your controller action to take your real view model, and not some hybrids and mixtures between view models and domain models:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddAddress(CustomerViewModel model)
{
    return Json(model);
}
```

and finally adapt your AJAX call:

```
function AddAddress() { 
    $.ajax({ 
        url: '@Url.Action("AddAddress", "Customer")', 
        type: 'POST', 
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 
        data: JSON.stringify({ 
            addresses: [
                { 
                    id : $('#lstID').val(), 
                    name : $('#lstAddName option:selected').text()
                }
            ],
            someOtherPropertyOnYourViewModel: 'some other value'
        }), 
        success: function (data) {

        } 
    }); 
}
```